# Cannot import <app>. Check that <path> is correct

Tags: django, signals, django-apps

I have a next structure of project

[image]

I want to create a signal in a `blog application`, but I get an error

> Cannot import 'blog'. Check that 'project.blog.apps.BlogConfig.name'
>   is correct.

If I write `default_app_config = 'blog.apps.BlogConfig'` in **__init__.py** I get error:

> No module named 'blog'

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    # project apps
    'project.blog',
    #...
]
```

**apps.py**

```
class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'

    def ready(self):
        import blog.signals
```

**__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'project.blog.apps.BlogConfig'
```

Comment: Can you try adding `'blog'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` insteead of `'project.blog'`?

Comment: If the name of your app is `project.blog` then use that everywhere (also in imports: `import project.blog.signals`). But your project structure is unconventional for Django projects. Your apps directories are at the wrong level. The should be at the same level as `manage.py`.